# Creation of GlassFish domain for CONNECT deployment error

Tags: windows, glassfish, asadmin

Running ant -Dglassfish.home=%AS_HOME% -f deploy.xml recreate.glassfish.domain

Generates the following error.

Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "%AS_HOME%\bin\asadmin.bat": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is, in the bin-directory there are two files:
asadmin.bat and asadmin (Linux-Executable).

Just rename or delete the Linux-Executable and the deployment works fine.